# Child Package Hides a Package from Another Child Package

Tags: ada

I have three packages: `Vendor.Apple`, `Vendor.Pear` and `Pear`.

In `Vendor.Apple`, there is a need to call subprograms from package `Pear`. However, importing (`with`) the `Pear` package, then attempting to call procedure `Eat` therein, results in the compiler thinking that the `Eat` procedure is inside `Vendor.Pear`. This results in the following error:

> "Eat" not declared in "Pear"

Is there a way to `with` using an absolute package path; work around the fact that the child package `Apple` has access to a "token" that hides the package we are attempting to import?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All library-level packages are implicitly declared in package `Standard`, see [ARM 10.1.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-10-1-1.html).

Say `Standard.Pear.Eat` (you don’t need `with Standard;`, in fact I’m not sure that’s even legal!)